# MinecraftForge 1.8 Imports Not Working

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft-forge

I have recently started modding in Minecraft 1.8, with Eclipse. I created a test mod, and it worked perfectly. Then I decided to start a new mod from scratch.

Almost immediately, I got an error by my imports.

I tried pressing Ctrl+Shift+O, to organize my imports, and it just deleted them, because they couldn't be resolved. I tried going back to my previous project, and the imports weren't working there either.

After some playing around, I realized that other imports *were* working.

**Only net.minecraftforge imports weren't working.**

I am extremely confused as to why this is happening. If you need me to upload my code, I will gladly do so. I greatly appreciate your help in advance. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When something goes askew with Eclipse when modding it's important to first check if the workspace is still good.
Sometimes for whatever reason a jar can get corrupted, deleted, locked by virusscanner, aliens kidnap it...

reason why isn't important unless you are into such a thing, but if you are solution minded first try to reset your workspace.

By running **`gradlew setupDecompWorkspace eclipse`** you redownload the stuff, re-decompile the jars and re-setup all the workspace items eclipse needs.

If your problem isn't solved after that you have a more serious issue.

Then I suggest you start really afresh.

Redownload the forge src from http://files.minecraftforge.net, extract it to a **new** directory and then run **`gradlew setupDecompWorkspace eclipse`** in that directory.
Then copy over your source files and see if the issue is resolved.

Then slowly add  your dependencies/external jars.

Comment: Not really. Gradle works in a way that it does not redownload unless the SHA-1 and MD5 sums of the 2 files do not match. Thats why forge uses it.